# 80s Sci-Fi movie with "fire-lion / fire-wolf" chasing people through locked steel doors

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I am looking for a sci-fi movie that I saw on late night German television in the early nineties, and I believe it must have been made sometime in the eighties.

I remember that a man (and a woman?) were being chased by some "thing" through a series of large steel doors or gates. They shut each gate behind them in order to stop the thing from reaching them. The "thing" was some kind of gigantic lion or wolf (not sure about this) made of fire or plasma and it slowly melted through the metal gates one after another, getting closer and closer to the two. The two seemed very desperate and knew that they would ultimately fail to escape.

The camera kept cutting back and forth between the thing on the outside, with loud, roaring noises and the two on the inside where it was very quiet. I believe that they were waiting after each gate, hoping that it would hold, but it slowly began to glow reddish as the thing was burning through it.
I vaguely remember the structure with the gates being underneath the surface of a planet with sandstorms.

I know that this is not a lot of information, but maybe someone will recognize the movie?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't really know that movie, but from your description and my google- foo it might have been "Forbidden Planet" from 1956.

The [IMDB- Entry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049223/?ref_=ttgf_gf_tt) features a video, that shows exactly the scene you describe around min 2:47.

[This video](https://youtu.be/IYFr3UyVpRA?t=2m10s) on youtube shows the monster itself starting at 2:18, that really looks like a lion or wolf.

The [wiki- article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet) about that movie describes the scene you pointed out as:

> The monster melts through the almost indestructible Krell metal doors of the laboratory where Adams, Altaira and Morbius have taken refuge

Comment: Fantastic answer! This is indeed the movie I was looking for. +1 for finding the additional videos which contain the scene I described.
Just one thing, I believe the youtube video you meant is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYFr3UyVpRA) one. Your link is about the movie, but doesn't show the monster.

Comment: starting from 2:18 of the video you see the parts of the monster ...